# Using isset() for user verification

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I am trying to make a home page that displays the users profile in the page. I used isset and session to check if the user is signed in or not. I get to the home page but everytime i refresh it it takes me back to the login even though the value is set.

I have tried using

```
if(empty($username)){

... script to take me back to login

}
```

```php
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo $username;

if(!isset($username))
{

echo "
<script>
window.location.href = 'login.php'; // Prevention of users not logged it to enter
</script>
";

}
else
{

$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
$lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
$img = $_SESSION['img'];
$name = "$fname $lname";


$prerl = $_SESSION['role'];
if($prerl === "1")
{

    $role = "Administrator";

}
else if($prerl === '2')
{

    $role = "Manager";

}
else if($prerl === '3')
{

    $role = "Cashier";

}

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title> Mamacita • Home </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homeStyle.css">
<meta charset = "utf8">

</head>

<body>

<div class = "home-sidebar-display">

<?php

    echo "<image src='$img'></image><br>";
    echo "Cashier: $name<br>";
    echo "Role: $role<br>";

?>

</div>

<div class = "home-menu-display">


<button onclick = "<?php session_destroy(); ?>"> Logout </button>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I expect the page to be in home.php even if I refresh the page. Any ideas?

Comment: no need to inject JS into PHP to redirect a user - use `header('Location: /path')`

Comment: `<button onclick = "<?php session_destroy(); ?>"` what? You're confusing PHP with JavaScript

Comment: You can't call PHP functions on the client side. You're calling `session_destroy()` every time the script runs, not just when the user clicks on the logout button.

Comment: You never set `$_SESSION['username']` in this code

Comment: I didn't find your mysql code. Why do you tag it with mysql?? This is a php session issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the backend and front end please look at the them.
If you good understand them ,you can't use as below code

It's wrong

```
<button onclick="<?php session_destroy(); ?>logout </button>
```

When window onload will all session destroyed !
You should as below code

logout.php

```
session_destroy();

header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Your button code

```
<button  onclick="logout()">logout</button>
```

Js code for logout func

```
function logout()
{
  window.location.href="logout.php";

}
```